# Why can't GHCi resolve the kind of [[]]?

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, ghc

Why can't Haskell resolve the kind of [[]] (A list of lists)?
Why isn't it simply * -> *, as I can give it a type like Int, and get [[Int]], which is of kind *.

Comment: it's kind of like asking why GHC can't figure out the type of the value `sqrt sqrt` even though `sqrt` itself is `Double -> Double`

Comment: :t sqrt sqrt works fine in GHCI though

Comment: It's because `sqrt` is polymorphic. A better analogy is :t not not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's the same as with `Maybe Maybe`, although in the latter case the reason is perhaps clearer: the "outer" type constructor expects to be passed a type of kind `*`, but sees a type constructor of type `* -> *` (the "inner" `Maybe` / `[]`) and complains. If I'm correct, this is not really a problem with the `:kind` functionality of GHCi, but rather with finding the correct syntax to express the composition of higher-kinded type constructors.

As a workaround, something like

```
:kind forall a. [[a]]
:kind forall a. Maybe (Maybe a)
```

can be used (with the appropriate language extension turned on -- `ExistentialQuantification`, I think -- to enable the `forall` syntax).

Comment: This thread from Haskell Café might be relevant: http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/msg08530.html -- Composition of Type Constructors.

Comment: I don't think existential type was intended (which is `*`). An easy way, but outside GHCi, is `type a = [[a]]` (which is `* -> *`).

Comment: @sdcvvc that's a universally quantified polymorphic type (not an existential).

Comment: @sdcvvc: The `forall` lines where meant as a means of making sure what the kind of the type constructors at hand is when there's a reasonable guess available -- if one suspects that `Foo` and `Bar` are both `* -> *`, checking whether the kind of `forall a. Foo (Bar a)` is `*` is one way of confirming that. I guess I haven't made it very clear. That's the best I can think of inside GHCi... In a regular source file, one can write `type Foo a = [[a]]` with the view to type `:k Foo` in GHCi to get back the missing `* ->` from the front, yeah.

Answer (score 4):

If we desugar `[[]]` as `[] []` then it's obvious that it is poorly kinded because `[] :: * -> *`.

If you actually wanted a "list of lists" you need to compose two type constructors of kind `* -> *`. You can't do that without a little boilerplate because Haskell doesn't have a type-level lambda. You can do this though:

```
newtype Comp f g a = Comp { unComp :: f (g a) }
```

Now you can write:

```
type ListList = Comp [] []
```

And write functions using it:

```
f :: ListList Int -> ListList Int
f = Comp . map (map (+1)) . unComp
```

Functor composition like this has applications in several areas, notably Swierstra's ["Data types a la carte"](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~wss/Publications/DataTypesALaCarte.pdf)